# iOS Networking Layer Architecture

Tags: ios, oop, networking, mvvm, rx-swift

**Reason For Post**

There are so many different solutions & examples on how to build a proper networking layer, but every app has different constraints, and design decisions are made based on trade-offs, leaving me uncertain about the quality of code I've written. If there are any `Anti-Patterns`, `redundancies`, or flat out bad solutions within my code that I have overlooked or simply lacked the knowledge to address, **please** do critique. This is a project I'd like to add to my portfolio, so I'm posting it here to get eyes on it, with some *advice/tips*.

**Thanks for your time in advanced!**

Some characteristics of my networking layer that I think could raise eyebrows:

`Method` contains a `GETALL` case, to indicate a list of data that must be fetched. I have not seen this in any of the open source code I've read. Is this a code smell?

```
enum Method {
    case GET
    /// Indicates how JSON response should be handled differently to abastract a list of entities
    case GETALL
    case PUT
    case DELETE
}
```

I've made it, so each Swift Entity conforms to JSONable protocol, meaning it can be initialized with json and converted to json.

```
protocol JSONable {
    init?(json: [String: AnyObject])
    func toJSON() -> Data?
}
```

JSONable in practice with one of my entities:

```
struct User {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var rating: Double
    var keywords: NSArray
    var profileImageUrl: String
}

extension User: JSONable {
    init?(json: [String : AnyObject]) {
        guard let id = json[Constant.id] as? String, let name = json[Constant.name] as? String, let location = json[Constant.location] as? String, let rating = json[Constant.rating] as? Double, let keywords = json[Constant.keywords] as? NSArray, let profileImageUrl = json[Constant.profileImageUrl] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(id: id, name: name, location: location, rating: rating, keywords: keywords, profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl)
    }

    func toJSON() -> Data? {

        let data: [String: Any] = [Constant.id: id, Constant.name: name, Constant.location: location, Constant.rating: rating, Constant.keywords: keywords, Constant.profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
        return jsonData
    }
}
```

This allows me to use `generics` to initialize all my entities in my client- `FirebaseAPI`, after I retrieve JSON response. I also haven't seen this technique in the code I've read.

In the code below, notice how `GETALL` is implemented to flatten the list of JSON objects. Should I have to do this at all? Is there a better way to handle any type of Json structure response?

**AND** Entities are initialized generically, and returned as an `Observable` ( Using RxSwift ).

Do you sense any code smells?

```
/// Responsible for Making actual API requests & Handling response
    /// Returns an observable object that conforms to JSONable protocol.
    /// Entities that confrom to JSONable just means they can be initialized with json & transformed from swift to JSON.
    func rx_fireRequest<Entity: JSONable>(_ endpoint: FirebaseEndpoint, ofType _: Entity.Type ) -> Observable<[Entity]> {

        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in

            self?.session.dataTask(with: endpoint.request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                /// Parse response from request.
                let parsedResponse = Parser(data: data, response: response, error: error)
                    .parse()

                switch parsedResponse {

                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                    return

                case .success(let data):
                    var entities = [Entity]()
                    switch endpoint.method { 

                    /// Flatten JSON strucuture to retrieve a list of entities.
                    /// Denoted by 'GETALL' method.
                    case .GETALL:

                        /// Key (underscored) is unique identifier for each entity
                        /// value is k/v pairs of entity attributes.
                        for (_, value) in data {
                            if let value = value as? [String: AnyObject], let entity = Entity(json: value) {
                                entities.append(entity)
                            }
                        }
                        /// Force downcast for generic type inference.
                        observer.onNext(entities as! [Entity])
                        //observer.onCompleted()

                    /// All other methods return JSON that can be used to initialize JSONable entities 
                    default:
                        if let entity = Entity(json: data) {
                        observer.onNext([entity] as! [Entity])
                        //observer.onCompleted()
                    } else {
                        observer.onError(NetworkError.initializationFailure)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

I manage different endpoints like so:

```
enum FirebaseEndpoint {
    case saveUser(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchUser(id: String)
    case removeUser(id: String)

    case saveItem(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchItem(id: String)
    case fetchItems
    case removeItem(id: String)

    case saveMessage(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchMessages(chatroomId: String)
    case removeMessage(id: String)
}


extension FirebaseEndpoint: Endpoint {

    var base: String {
        // Add this as a constant to APP Secrts struct & dont include secrets file when pushed to github.
        return "https://AppName.firebaseio.com"
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .saveUser(let data): return "/\(Constant.users)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .fetchUser(let id): return "/\(Constant.users)/\(id)"
        case .removeUser(let id): return "/\(Constant.users)/\(id)"

        case .saveItem(let data): return "/\(Constant.items)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .fetchItem(let id): return "/\(Constant.items)/\(id)"
        case .fetchItems: return "/\(Constant.items)"
        case .removeItem(let id): return "/\(Constant.items)/\(id)"

        case .saveMessage(let data): return "/\(Constant.messages)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .fetchMessages(let chatroomId): return "\(Constant.messages)/\(chatroomId)"
        case .removeMessage(let id): return "/\(Constant.messages)/\(id)"
        }
    }

    var method: Method {
        switch self {
        case .fetchUser, .fetchItem: return .GET
        case .fetchItems, .fetchMessages: return .GETALL
        case .saveUser, .saveItem, .saveMessage: return .PUT
        case .removeUser, .removeItem, .removeMessage: return .DELETE
        }
    }

    var body: [String : AnyObject]? {
        switch self {
        case .saveItem(let data), .saveUser(let data), .saveMessage(let data): return data
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Last thing, I'd like someone with professional eyes to look at is, how I use MVVM. I make all network requests from view model,  which comes out looking something like this:

```
struct SearchViewModel {

    // Outputs
    var collectionItems: Observable<[Item]>
    var error: Observable<Error>

    init(controlValue: Observable<Int>, api: FirebaseAPI, user: User) {

        let serverItems = controlValue
            .map { ItemCategory(rawValue: $0) }
            .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
            .flatMap { api.rx_fetchItems(for: user, category: $0)
                .materialize()
            }
            .filter { !$0.isCompleted }
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        collectionItems = serverItems.filter { $0.element != nil }.dematerialize()
        error = serverItems.filter { $0.error != nil }.map { $0.error! }
    }

}
```

In order to call api requests in a more expressive, formalized way, I am able to call `api.rx_fetchItems(for:)` inside `flatmap` above, because I `extend` `FirebaseAPI` to conform to `FetchItemsAPI`. I will probably have to follow the same pattern for most other requests.

```
extension FirebaseAPI: FetchItemsAPI {

    // MARK: Fetch Items Protocol

    func rx_fetchItems(for user: User, category: ItemCategory) -> Observable<[Item]>  {
        // fetched items returns all items in database as Observable<[Item]>
        let fetchedItems = rx_fireRequest(.fetchItems, ofType: Item.self)

        switch category {

        case .Local:
            let localItems = fetchedItems
                .flatMapLatest { (itemList) -> Observable<[Item]> in
                    return self.rx_localItems(user: user, items: itemList)
            }
            return localItems


        case .RecentlyAdded:
            // Compare current date to creation date of item. If its within 24 hours, It makes the cut. 
            let recentlyAddedItems = fetchedItems
                .flatMapLatest { (itemList) -> Observable<[Item]> in
                    return self.rx_recentlyAddedItems(items: itemList)
            }
            return recentlyAddedItems


        case .Trending:

            let trendingItems = fetchedItems
                .flatMapLatest { (itemList) -> Observable<[Item]> in
                    return self.rx_trendingItems(items: itemList)
            }
            return trendingItems


        default:

            let stubItem = Item(id: "DEFAULT", createdById: "createdBy", creationDate: 1.3, expirationDate: 2.4, title: "title", price: 2, info: "info", imageUrl: "url", bidCount: 4, location: "LA")
            return Observable.just([stubItem])
        }
    }




    // MARK: Helper Methods

    private func rx_localItems(user: User, items: [Item]) -> Observable<[Item]> {
        return Observable<[Item]>.create { observer in
            observer.onNext(items.filter { $0.location == user.location }) // LA Matches stubs in db
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }


    func rx_recentlyAddedItems(items: [Item]) -> Observable<[Item]> {
        return Observable<[Item]>.create { observer in
            let recentItems = items
                .filter {
                    let now = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
                    let creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0.creationDate)
                    if let hoursAgo = now.offset(from: creationDate, units: [.hour], maxUnits: 1) {
                        return Int(hoursAgo)! < 24
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
            }
            observer.onNext(recentItems)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }


    func rx_trendingItems(items: [Item]) -> Observable<[Item]> {
        return Observable<[Item]>.create { observer in
            observer.onNext(items.filter { $0.bidCount > 8 })
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }




}
```

I'm attempting to follow SOLID principles, and level up with RxSWift + MVVM, so I'm still unsure about the best OOP design for clean, maintainable code.

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.